# Prove $(A'\times B) \cup (A\times C) = (A'\cup A) \times (B\cup C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I have been working on this proof for more than 6 hours by now and I still can't find a proper way to prove that the proposition is false, or potentially true.

For finite sets $A, B, C, \subset U$ prove $$
(A' \times B) \cup (A \times C) = (A' \cup A) \times (B \cup C)$$

Above, $A' := U \setminus A$.
I know $(A' \cup A) \times (B \cup C)$ is equivalent to $U \times (B \cup C)$ by the complement law. This is the only definition i have found that can help the proof.

I can't seem to go any further than this...

Help, please.

Comment: Why do you think this is true?

Comment: What is $A'$ here?

Comment: To show it's false, try to find a counterexample. It can be small. Try $U=\{1,2,3\}$ and choose $A$, $B$, and $C$ to be subsets of that.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I do not think it is true. The thing is : how can i formally prove that it is false?

Comment: @DrewBrady I believe $A'$ is the complement of $A$, so $U\setminus A$.

Comment: Just take $U=\{u,v\}, A=\{u\}, A'=\{v\}, B=\{b\}, C=\{c\}$ and check what the left side turns out to be, and also the right side. What you *can* prove is that the left side is always a subset of the right side, but not the other way round.

Comment: To formally prove a statement is false, give an explicit counterexample by proving that the hypotheses are true (in this case that $A$, $B$, and $C$ are subsets of $U$) and prove that the conclusion is false (in this case that the equality fails to hold).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty clear that these are generally not the same set.

The right hand side has elements of the form $(u, x)$ for $u \in U$ and $x \in B$ or $x \in C$.

The left hand side has elements of the form $(a, c)$ for $a \in A$ and $c \in C$, or $(a', b)$ for $a' \not \in A, b\in B$. In particular, it does not have elements of the form $(u, x)$ when $u \not \in A, x \in C$ nor if $u \in A, x \in B$.